# Why does my Gnome Sort algorithm cause my system to hang?

Tags: c#

This is my Gnome sort algorithm, for some reason when I use it, it causes my system to hang. I think it may have something to do with the `comparer.Compare(x,y) == 1` part but not sure.

```
    static public void GnomeSort<T>(IList<T> list)
    {
        GnomeSort<T>(list, Comparer<T>.Default);
    }

    static public void GnomeSort<T>(IList<T> list, IComparer<T> comparer)
    {
        bool stillGoing = true;
        while (stillGoing)
        {
            stillGoing = false;
            for (int i = 1; i < list.Count; )
            {
                T temp;
                T x = list[i - 1];
                T y = list[i];
                if (comparer.Compare(x,y) == 1)
                    i++;
                else
                {
                    temp = x;
                    x = y;
                    y = temp;
                    i--;
                    if (i == 0)
                        i = 1;
                    stillGoing = true;
                } 
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Not changing the list is the biggest issue, but you're right to identify your use of `Compare` as being a possible issue. The documented requirement for the [`IComparer<T> interface`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/xh5ks3b3.aspx) is merely that the returned values be less than, equal to, or greater than 0. The actual values for the less than and greater than cases could be anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You never change incoming list. So you always have unsorted list

```
   if (comparer.Compare(x,y) > 0)
   {
        i++;
   }
   else
   {
       list[i-1] = y;
       list[i] = x;
       i--;
       if (i == 0)
           i = 1;
       stillGoing = true;
    }
```

Comment: That won't change the list either. You are putting the values back in the same position.

Comment: Also change `if (comparer.Compare(x,y) == 1)` to `if (comparer.Compare(x,y) > 0)`

Comment: It still hangs when I set `(comparer.Compare(x,y) == 0)` to `(comparer.Compare(x,y) > 0)`

Comment: Using `if (comparer.Compare(x,y) > 1)` doesn't make sense. The comparer returns zero or a positive or negative number. A number that is larger than one doesn't have a different meaning than a number that is one.

Answer (score 2):

The `x` and `y` variables only contain copies of the data in the list, so swapping them doesn't swap the items in the list.

If `T` is a value type, the values are actual copies. If `T` is a reference type, the values are copies of the references to the actual data.

Change this:

```
temp = x;
x = y;
y = temp;
```

into:

```
list[i - 1] = y;
list[i] = x;
```